# How much do I have to rotate an object around X, Y, Z in order to make it parallel to a line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rigid-transformation

I have a cone-shape 3D object like this:

[image: cone 3D object]

I have a line with a normalized direction vector like this:

```
Normalized vector = (-0.702755, -0.514791, -0.491045)
```

I want to rotate my cone so that it is parallel to my direction vector. So far I have tried this:

```
Cone rotation around X = Arccos(-0.702755)
Cone rotation around y = Arccos(-0.514791)
Cone rotation around z = Arccos(-0.491045)
```

But it is not rotating cone properly, I mean my cone is still not parallel to the direction vector/line. I wonder what is the best practice to do so. Thanks.

## Update

Finally, the problem is resolved by the approach here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465275/3405291

Answer (score 1):

Call the normalized vector $u'=(a',b',c')$ (it is messy to type long decimal numbers!)
(So $a',b',c'$ are known specific constants)
I assume you already have a specific cone with axis one some other line $u$ that you want rotated to $u'$?

Take the info about the current axis vector $u=(a,b,c)$.
Here $a,b,c$ are also known (to you) specific constants, normalized.

Let $P$ and $P'$ be the planes for which $u$ and $u'$ are the normals.

SO they have equation $ax+by+cz=0, a'x+b'y+c'z=0$. Let $v,w$, and $v,'w'$ be vectors in $P$ and $P'$ forming orthornormal bases for $P$ and $P'$ respectively.

Now let $A, A'$ be the $3\times3$ matrices formed by these vectors as columns: $A=(u, v, w), \quad A'=(u',v',w')$.

Now the matrix $B= A'A^{-1}$ is the change-of-basis matrix needed.
This matrix $B$ is known as you already have $(a,b,c)$ and $(a',b',c')$.

So for your cone satisfying equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ replace the vector
$(x,y,z)$ by the $(x'y,z')=B\times (x,y,z)^T$. (here $\times$ means multiplying the square matrix by column vector)
Now $F(x',y',z')=0$ is the equation of the cone you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggested procedure, but for some reason it is not giving me the expected results. Maybe I have a bug in my code, I'm not sure. Anyway, I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52456521/3405291) and I'm studying [this q & a](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542801/197913) too.

Comment: Finally, the problem [got resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465275/3405291). I'm not sure what I was doing wrong with your method.